# How to have two or more Email accounts under the Get Message button in Thunderbird v52?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have an Email account with my primary ISP but I want add a Gmail account.

How do you do that so you can get messages form either account when
you click the get Messages button?

Comment: Is that not the default behaviour when you have multiple accounts in use?